# generate certificate using ECDSA in c#

Tags: c#, certificate, ecdsa

I'm trying to generate (self-signed) certificate with private key using ECDSA.
The goals is to get "the same" (pkcs12) certificate as when using openssl:

```
openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp256r1 -out mykey.key
openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out myreq.csr
openssl req -x509 -days 7 -key mykey.key -in myreq.csr -out mycert.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycert.pfx -inkey mykey.key -in mycert.crt
```

I already use BouncyCastle to help me with creating RSA-based certificate(s), so next steps more or less follow the way I use to create RSA certs.

(note that `BC` prefix is used for classes from BouncyCastle, `MS` for .NET classes)

**1** generate key pair: private and public keys

```
BC.IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator bcKpGen = BC.GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("ECDSA");
bcKpGen.Init(new BC.ECKeyGenerationParameters(BC.SecObjectIdentifiers.SecP256r1, new BC.SecureRandom()));
BC.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair bcSubjKeys = bcKpGen.GenerateKeyPair();
```

**2** use private key to sign public key with some additional data (subject, validity period etc)

```
BC.X509V3CertificateGenerator bcXgen = new BC.X509V3CertificateGenerator();
// .. set subject, validity period etc
bcXgen.SetPublicKey(bcSubjKeys.Public);
BC.ISignatureFactory bcSigFac = new BC.Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA256WITHECDSA", bcSubjKeys.Private);
BC.X509Certificate bcCert = bcXgen.Generate(bcSigFac);
```

**3** "join" private key from step1 and certificate from step2 to get certificate with private key.

If I'm ok with certificate without private key, I could do something like:

```
MS.X509Certificate mcCert = new MS.X509Certificate2(bcCert.GetEncoded(), null);
```

and I'm done.

The issue(s) come when trying to set private-key:

```
msCert.PrivateKey = ConvertBouncyToNetSomehow(bcSubjKeys.Private)
```

(note that typeof `msCert.PrivateKey` is `MS.AsymmetricAlgorithm` and the type of `bcSubjKeys.Private` is `BC.ECPrivateKeyParameters`)

It seems that suitable way is using `MS.ECDsaCng` class (which inherits from `MS.AsymmetricAlgorithm`), but:

**1** The only way I found to convert `BC.ECPrivateKeyParameters` to `MS.CngKey` (required by `MS.ECDsaCng`) is via pkcs8 format:

```
BC.PrivateKeyInfo bcPKInfo = BC.PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(bcSubjKeys.Private);
byte[] pkArr = bcPKInfo.GetDerEncoded();
MS.CngKey msPKCng = MS.CngKey.Import(pkArr, MS.CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
```

but using this approach some information is lost because value of `msPKCng.AlgorithmGroup` is `"ECDH"` while `bcSubjKeys.Private.AlgorithmName`says `"ECDSA"`. Also ECDH-key cannot be used with `MS.ECDsaCng`.

Nevertheless.. I could continue with `MS.ECDiffieHellmanCng` instead of requested `MS.ECDsaCng` if..

**2** implementation of `MS.X509Certificate2.set_PrivateKey` requires the object implements interface `MS.ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm`. But neither one of them (`ECDsaCng`, `ECDiffieHellmanCng`) implement it.

At this point it seems different approach must be used (because of `MS.ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm` condition), e.g. export certificate and private key to pkcs file and use `X509Certificate2.Import(..)`.

Any hint?
Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to do straight out of the box right now.  You can get the rest of the way with P/Invokes and .NET 4.6.2 (currently in preview). Or, with a detour through .NET Core you can build a PFX that works in .NET 4.6.1.

## "ECDSA" vs "ECDH"

The Windows CNG libraries split ECC into ECDSA and ECDH. ECDSA key objects can only be used for ECDSA; but whenever Windows can't determine the usage during a PFX import (or PKCS#8 import) it calls a private key ECDH.  Why? Because Windows lets ECDH key objects do both key agreement (ECDH) and digital signature (ECDSA), so ECDH is more flexible.

But .NET 4.6.1 didn't know that.

.NET Core doesn't have this limitation (see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/5850), and .NET 4.6.2 has also removed the restriction (per https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net462/dotnet462-changes.md#user-content-bcl).

## Generating "ECDSA" keys, instead of "ECDH"

.NET Core now has an [ImportParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa#System_Security_Cryptography_ECDsa_ImportParameters_System_Security_Cryptography_ECParameters_) method on ECDsa. If you can translate the BC.ECPrivateKeyProperty object to an MS.ECParameters structure you can import the blob into an ECDsaCng object. (Be sure to use it as a named curve, instead of explicitly copying all of the curve parameters).

Since it was purposefully imported into an ECDsa object it gets an ECDSA key, and that information will be embedded in the PFX.

## Building the PFX (tying it all together)

With a bit of P/Invoking you can convince Windows to build a PFX using an ephemeral key. While .NET can't access ephemeral private keys from certificates, it will be able to make use of it if loaded from a PFX:

```
[DllImport(Libraries.Crypt32, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern unsafe bool CertSetCertificateContextProperty(IntPtr pCertContext, CertContextPropId dwPropId, CertSetPropertyFlags dwFlags, SafeNCryptKeyHandle pvData);

internal enum CertContextPropId : int
{
    CERT_NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE_PROP_ID = 78,
}

[Flags]
internal enum CertSetPropertyFlags : int
{
    None = 0,
}

private static X509Certificate2 MateECDsaPrivateKey(
    X509Certificate2 cert,
    CngKey privateKey)
{
    // Make a new certificate instance which isn't tied to the current one
    using (var tmpCert = new X509Certificate2(cert.RawData))
    {
        SafeNCryptKeyHandle keyHandle = privateKey.Handle;

        // Set the ephemeral key handle property
        if (!CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
            tmpCert.Handle,
            CertContextPropId.CERT_NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE_PROP_ID,
            CertSetPropertyFlags.None,
            keyHandle))
        {
            throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        // You could emit this, if you prefer.
        byte[] pfxBytes = tmpCert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12);

        // Clear the key handle out again to prevent double-free
        keyHandle = new SafeNCryptKeyHandle();

        if (!CertSetCertificateContextProperty(
            tmpCert.Handle,
            CertContextPropId.CERT_NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE_PROP_ID,
            CertSetPropertyFlags.None,
            keyHandle))
        {
            throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        // Now load a new certificate which has a temporary keyfile on disk.
        // Note: If you don't want exportability here, don't request it.
        var matedCert = new X509Certificate2(pfxBytes, (string)null, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        using (ECDsa ecdsa = matedCert.GetECDsaPrivateKey())
        {
            if (ecdsa == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("It didn't work");
            }
        }

        return matedCert;
    }
}
```

You'll need .NET 4.6.1 (or newer) to have access to GetECDsaPrivateKey().

Comment: It didn't work :-( Any hints? @bartonjs Do you have a running example for .net 4.6.1/2

Comment: @DanielFisherlennybacon Looks like I had an & error (and a couple typos).  Given a valid PKCS8 blob which belongs to a valid cert blob, https://gist.github.com/bartonjs/fac9ea9108dd184a7a66be77f0af3fef worked for me.

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot

Comment: works as well. Working example based on .net4.7 can be found here: [Translating Elliptic Curve parameters (BC to MS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542233/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use MateECDsaPrivateKey by creating a self-signed X509 using CertificateRequest and passing ECDsa key. Then exporting the public key using Export(X509ContentType.Cert). Then using MateECDsaPrivateKey to reconnect the original Private key.

My use case is to create a X509 certificate to store a key needed for a ECDiffieHellman. The underlying Cng key handling doesn't like the key if it is not of the ECDH Algorithm group. Even if you set the underlying Cng key type Algorithm group to ECDH it gets reset to ECDsa. ECDiffieHellmanCng requires ECDH

By using MateECDsaPrivateKey I was able to reconnect the X509 public key the the correct ECDH private key. This is only an issue on Windows, on non-Windows platforms the underlying Key handling is less picky.

I created https://dev.azure.com/ctx-eng-automation-devops/ElipticCurveX509Certificates which runs the correct process according to the OS platform. It also has an extension to X509Certificate2 to use the correct method to extract the ECDH private key to create the ECDiffieHellman object.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ElipticCurveX509Certificates/