# Translating Elliptic Curve parameters (BC to MS)

Tags: c#, certificate, bouncycastle, ecdsa

I'm trying to generate ECDSA self-signed certificate as described in [generate certificate using ECDSA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624105/generate-certificate-using-ecdsa-in-c-sharp). Putting all pieces from bartonjs's answer together and using `Net.Framework 4.7` (or `Net.Core 2.0`) following code seems to be working although there are some ambiguities (at least one) left:

I'm not sure how to properly convert private key ('D' parameter) from `BC-BigInteger` to `MS-byte[]`. Using `BigInteger.ToByteArray()` throws exception:

> **CryptographicException**: The specified key parameters are not valid.
>   Q.X and Q.Y are required fields. Q.X, Q.Y must be the same length. If
>   D is specified it must be the same length as Q.X and Q.Y for named
>   curves or the same length as Order for explicit curves.

while validating ECParameters (method `ECParameters.Validate()`). Using `BigInteger.ToByteArrayUnsigned()` provides much better results (one failure on several hundred generated key-pairs), but still...

When using `ToByteArray()` converted 'D' is usually one byte longer ('D' has 33 bytes vs D.X and D.Y has 32 bytes). Using `ToByteArrayUnsigned()` the 'D' is sometimes one byte shorter.

So my question is whether is is ok to use `ToByteArrayUnsigned()`.

```
private const string NCryptExportPolicyProperty = "Export Policy";
private const string SignatureAlgorithm = "Sha256WithECDSA";
private static readonly ECCurve MsCurve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256;
private static readonly DerObjectIdentifier BcCurve = SecObjectIdentifiers.SecP256r1; // must correspond with MsCurve

public static X509Certificate2 Create()
{    
    // 1. generate keys:
    IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator bcKeyGen = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("ECDSA");
    bcKeyGen.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(BcCurve, new SecureRandom()));

    ECPrivateKeyParameters bcPrivKey;
    ECPublicKeyParameters bcPublKey;

    bool validated;
    ECParameters msEcp;
    do
    {
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair bcKeyPair = bcKeyGen.GenerateKeyPair();
        bcPrivKey = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)bcKeyPair.Private;
        bcPublKey = (ECPublicKeyParameters)bcKeyPair.Public;

        // 2. ensure generated bc-keys can be translated to cng (see exception below)
        msEcp = new ECParameters();
        msEcp.Curve = MsCurve;
        msEcp.D = bcPrivKey.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned(); // or bcPrivKey.D.ToByteArray() ??
        msEcp.Q.X = bcPublKey.Q.XCoord.GetEncoded();
        msEcp.Q.Y = bcPublKey.Q.YCoord.GetEncoded();

        try
        {
            msEcp.Validate();
            validated = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Validate() occasionally throws CryptographicException: 
            // The specified key parameters are not valid. Q.X and Q.Y are required fields. Q.X, Q.Y must be the same length. If D is specified it must be the same length as Q.X and Q.Y for named curves or the same length as Order for explicit curves.
            // e.g.: D = 31, Q.X = 32, Q.Y = 32.
            validated = false;
            Console.WriteLine("D = {0}, Q.X = {1}, Q.Y = {2}. {3}: {4}", msEcp.D.Length, msEcp.Q.X.Length, msEcp.Q.Y.Length, e.GetType().Name, e.Message);
        }
    } while (!validated);

    // 3. create x509 certificate:
    X509V3CertificateGenerator bcCertGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
    bcCertGen.SetPublicKey(bcPublKey);
    // .. set subject, validity period etc
    ISignatureFactory sigFac = new Asn1SignatureFactory(SignatureAlgorithm, bcPrivKey);
    Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate bcX509Cert = bcCertGen.Generate(sigFac);
    byte[] x509CertEncoded = bcX509Cert.GetEncoded();

    X509Certificate2 msNewCert;

    // 4. use translated (and validated) parameters:
    using (ECDsaCng msEcdsa = new ECDsaCng())
    {
        msEcdsa.ImportParameters(msEcp);

        CngKey msPrivateKey = msEcdsa.Key;

        // 5. make private key exportable:
        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes((int)(CngExportPolicies.AllowExport | CngExportPolicies.AllowPlaintextExport));
        CngProperty pty = new CngProperty(NCryptExportPolicyProperty, bytes, CngPropertyOptions.Persist);
        msPrivateKey.SetProperty(pty);

        // 6. tie keys together:
        using (X509Certificate2 msPubCertOnly = new X509Certificate2(x509CertEncoded))
        {
            msNewCert = MateECDsaPrivateKey(msPubCertOnly, msPrivateKey); // method from bartonjs's answer
        }
    }

    return msNewCert;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: When D is 33 bytes D[0] is probably 0.  You want to not have the padding zero if that's the case.  When D is 31 bytes (or smaller) you need to insert 0s at the beginning.  Of course, it's hard to prove that without examples of failure.

Comment: You right. Adding/Removing of leading zeros ensures that the validation passes. But is that ok? Is the key/certificate with "fixed" key ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are getting too many bytes (33 in this case) the first byte should be `0x00`, and you need to remove it.  When you are getting too few (technically speaking D=1 is valid) you need to insert zeros to fill the array out.

The reason is that .NET's structure expects D to look like it does to the underlying Windows CNG import API, which means that D is a fixed-with unsigned big endian big integer.  BouncyCastle is giving you the BER INTEGER encoding, which requires inserting a `0x00` byte when the high bit of the most significant byte (bytes[0], big endian) is set in a number that should be considered positive.

BER also has a rule that the minimum number of bytes be used, which is why sometimes BouncyCastle gives a number that's too small.

Q.X and Q.Y are okay because the ECPoint encoding rules specify a fixed size big endian integer whose size is determined by the curve; which is why BouncyCastle has the `GetEncoded` method instead of just `ToByteArrayUnsigned`.

```
private static byte[] FixSize(byte[] input, int expectedSize)
{
    if (input.Length == expectedSize)
    {
        return input;
    }

    byte[] tmp;

    if (input.Length < expectedSize)
    {
        tmp = new byte[expectedSize];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(input, 0, tmp, expectedSize - input.Length, input.Length);
        return tmp;
    }

    if (input.Length > expectedSize + 1 || input[0] != 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    tmp = new byte[expectedSize];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(input, 1, tmp, 0, expectedSize);
    return tmp;
}

...

msEcp = new ECParameters();
msEcp.Curve = MsCurve;
msEcp.Q.X = bcPublKey.Q.XCoord.GetEncoded();
msEcp.Q.Y = bcPublKey.Q.YCoord.GetEncoded();
msEcp.D = FixSize(bcPrivKey.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned(), msEcp.Q.X.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will help you, you can generate algorithm using bouncy castle library:

```
private static ECDsa GetEllipticCurveAlgorithm(string privateKey)
    {
        var keyParams = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory
            .CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));

        var normalizedECPoint = keyParams.Parameters.G.Multiply(keyParams.D).Normalize();

        return ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
        {
            Curve = ECCurve.CreateFromValue(keyParams.PublicKeyParamSet.Id),
            D = keyParams.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Q =
        {
            X = normalizedECPoint.XCoord.GetEncoded(),
            Y = normalizedECPoint.YCoord.GetEncoded()
        }
        });
    }
```

and generate the token in the following way:

```
var signatureAlgorithm = GetEllipticCurveAlgorithm(privateKey);

            ECDsaSecurityKey eCDsaSecurityKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(signatureAlgorithm)
            {
                KeyId = settings.Apple.KeyId
            };

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();   
            var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: iss,
                audience: AUD,
                subject: new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> { new Claim("sub", sub) }),
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5), 
                issuedAt: DateTime.UtcNow,
                notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(eCDsaSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256));
```