# How to read ES512 private key in .NET Framework

Tags: cryptography, jwt, .net-framework-version, ecdsa

I'm trying to read ES512 private key to create JWT token in .NET Framework 4.7.2 but it throws validation   exception when I'm creating ECDsa object.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The specified key parameters are not valid. Q.X and Q.Y are required fields. Q.X, Q.Y must be the same length. If D is specified it must be the same length as Q.X and Q.Y for named curves or the same length as Order for explicit curves.'
```

What is wrong here? I checked internet and couldn't find any solution. In NET Core 3 it is working with ImportECPrivateKey method but I don't know how to do this in .NET Framework which I need.

```
class Program
{
    static string privateKey = @"MIHcAgEBBEIBiyAa7aRHFDCh2qga9sTUGINE5jHAFnmM8xWeT/uni5I4tNqhV5Xx0pDrmCV9mbroFtfEa0XVfKuMAxxfZ6LM/yKgBwYFK4EEACOhgYkDgYYABAGBzgdnP798FsLuWYTDDQA7c0r3BVk8NnRUSexpQUsRilPNv3SchO0lRw9Ru86x1khnVDx+duq4BiDFcvlSAcyjLACJvjvoyTLJiA+TQFdmrearjMiZNE25pT2yWP1NUndJxPcvVtfBW48kPOmvkY4WlqP5bAwCXwbsKrCgk6xbsp12ew==";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var derArray = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
        LoadPrivateKey(derArray);
    }

    private static ECDsa LoadPrivateKey(byte[] key)
    {
        var privKeyInt = new Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger(+1, key);
        var parameters = SecNamedCurves.GetByName("secp521r1");
        var ecPoint = parameters.G.Multiply(privKeyInt);
        var privKeyX = ecPoint.Normalize().XCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        var privKeyY = ecPoint.Normalize().YCoord.ToBigInteger().ToByteArrayUnsigned();

        return ECDsa.Create(new ECParameters
        {
            Curve = ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP521,
            D = privKeyInt.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
            Q = new ECPoint
            {
                X = privKeyX,
                Y = privKeyY
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While .NET Core directly supports the import of key formats like PKCS#1, PKCS#8, SEC1 and X.509/SPKI, this is not the case with .NET Framework. Here is one way to use [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html). E.g. for the posted [SEC1](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/84331) key:

```
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
...
string privateKey = @"-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
                    MIHcAgEBBEIBiyAa7aRHFDCh2qga9sTUGINE5jHAFnmM8xWeT/uni5I4tNqhV5Xx
                    0pDrmCV9mbroFtfEa0XVfKuMAxxfZ6LM/yKgBwYFK4EEACOhgYkDgYYABAGBzgdn
                    P798FsLuWYTDDQA7c0r3BVk8NnRUSexpQUsRilPNv3SchO0lRw9Ru86x1khnVDx+
                    duq4BiDFcvlSAcyjLACJvjvoyTLJiA+TQFdmrearjMiZNE25pT2yWP1NUndJxPcv
                    VtfBW48kPOmvkY4WlqP5bAwCXwbsKrCgk6xbsp12ew==
                    -----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----"; 
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(privateKey));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ecKeyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemReader.ReadObject();
ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPrivateKeyParams = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)ecKeyPair.Private;
ECPublicKeyParameters ecPublicKeyParams = (ECPublicKeyParameters)ecKeyPair.Public;
```

Signing/verifying is supported by BouncyCastle's `SignerUtilities` class, e.g:

```
byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-512withECDSA");
signer.Init(true, ecPrivateKeyParams);
signer.BlockUpdate(message, 0, message.Length);
byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();
```

The generated signature is returned in ASN.1 format. Newer BC versions also support `SHA-512withPLAIN-ECDSA`, which returns a signature in r|s format. This is interesting in the context of JWT, because JWT uses the r|s format.

Alternatively, an [`ECDsa`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdsa?view=netframework-4.8) instance can be applied for signing/verifying (as obviously intended in the code posted in the question):

```
ECDsa ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ecParams);
```

where the `Create()` method expects a `System.Security.Cryptography.ECParameters` instance. The latter can be derived from the `ECPrivateKeyParameters`/`ECPublicKeyParameters` instances, which is described in detail in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48547186).

Answer (score 1):

This is a PKCS#8 / DER encoded private key. DER encoding consists of a lot more than just the private element. In this case it also has a version number, the name of the curve and whats probably the EC public point. You can view the contents [here on Lapo.it](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIHcAgEBBEIBiyAa7aRHFDCh2qga9sTUGINE5jHAFnmM8xWeT_uni5I4tNqhV5Xx0pDrmCV9mbroFtfEa0XVfKuMAxxfZ6LM_yKgBwYFK4EEACOhgYkDgYYABAGBzgdnP798FsLuWYTDDQA7c0r3BVk8NnRUSexpQUsRilPNv3SchO0lRw9Ru86x1khnVDx-duq4BiDFcvlSAcyjLACJvjvoyTLJiA-TQFdmrearjMiZNE25pT2yWP1NUndJxPcvVtfBW48kPOmvkY4WlqP5bAwCXwbsKrCgk6xbsp12ew). Recalculating the public key is relatively fast, so you can probably do without the optional public key.

To decode it you need specialized classes such as [`Pkcs8PrivateKeyInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.pkcs8privatekeyinfo?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0). After that you can [extract the private key bytes from the class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.pkcs8privatekeyinfo.privatekeybytes?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_Pkcs_Pkcs8PrivateKeyInfo_PrivateKeyBytes). Note that it is a **big endian** encoded number, so that part of your code needs to stay intact.

Actually, with the private key as bytes I think that the whole of `LoadPrivateKey` would still be correct (other than the name, I expect some kind of IO when I see `load` in a name).